# Why do clang and gcc duplicate code and branch vs unconditional jump inside loop?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, x86

Why do compilers seem to prefer to optimize pretest loops into a check, conditional jump over, then a do-while structure, versus doing an unconditional jump inside the the do while loop?

I wrote a function that is written in the second style I described, but both g++ and clang undo it and transform it into method one.
https://godbolt.org/g/2Dvudi

I'm confused because it seems like the compiler duplicates a lot of instructions (maybe not that much for this example) for the pretest. Also, It may do a jump anyway (though maybe it is statically predicted to be not taken, and not a big deal in the average case), so why not just do an unconditional jump always?

Here is one thought I have about it, but It doesn't strongly support either method:
The loop wants to be aligned, so there may be room to duplicate some instructions upfront anyway without wasting space, since they'd be padded with nops. However, both clang and gcc emit code that exceeds 16-bytes for the pretest, and end up inserting a large nop afterwards.

Edit: Here is the code from the godbolt link:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;

unsigned my_atoi(const uchar *p)//sentinel at end
{
  unsigned acm=0u;
  unsigned d;
  goto LEnter;
  do{
    acm =  acm*10u + d;
  LEnter:
    d = *p++ - '0';
  }while (d<10u);
  return acm;
}
```

clang 5.0 at -O2 emits:

```
my_atoi(unsigned char const*):                          # @my_atoi(unsigned char const*)
    movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rdi]
    add     ecx, -48
    xor     eax, eax
    cmp     ecx, 9
    ja      .LBB0_3
    inc     rdi
    xor     eax, eax
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    lea     eax, [rax + 4*rax]
    lea     eax, [rcx + 2*rax]
    movzx   ecx, byte ptr [rdi]
    add     ecx, -48
    inc     rdi
    cmp     ecx, 10
    jb      .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
    ret
```

Comment: Not-taken jumps are slightly cheaper than taken, so peeling the first iteration seems reasonable.  Probably it's just a side-effect of transforming through the compiler's internal representation on the way from src to asm.  Interestingly, `clang -Oz` (optimize for size without caring about performance) uses your loop structure.  IMO gcc and clang should jump into the loop (like your source) at `-Os` (optimize somewhat for size, but don't sacrifice too much speed).  If I have time, I'll post this up as an answer.

Comment: And BTW, gcc doesn't keep track of alignment during code-gen.  It just decides to emit `.p2align` based on tuning options that don't include tracking how close it actually is to an alignment boundary.    (BTW, it would be better to include the src + asm from one of the compilers in your question, as well as the Godbolt link)

Comment: Here's an educated guess: Modern processors keep branch prediction state associated with each conditional branch. So this code makes sense if it's profitable to predict the case of zero iterations separately from the case of more than zero. E.g. in cases where the loop is often skipped, but when entered executes more than a few iterations, this scheme would generate much better predictions than a single branch.  Branch prediction can have a huge (as in factor of 10 or 20) effect on performance, so it's worth a few extra instructions to increase likelihood of success.

Comment: @Gene: Hmm, I wonder if gcc and clang would still make the same choice about layout with profile-guided optimization (`-fprofile-generate` / run it with some test data / `-fprofile-use`).  If you got different results from a test set that included many cases of the loop running zero or 1 times (both branches not taken) vs. a case where the loop branch was always taken at least a couple times, that would lend some weight to that theory.  Although it could just be that compilers are designed to always try to lay out loops that way because it can often be better for that reason.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd suspect the latter. The cost of the extra branch is one or two more instructions in the binary. The number of instructions executed is the same. I would think it not worth the trouble to decide whether to add the extras with pgo.  But you never know. Compiler writers can be obsessive ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting some comments from [GCC sources](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/tree-ssa-loop-ch.c) of a relevant optimization pass.

> Duplicates headers of loops if they are small enough, so that the statements
>    in the loop body are always executed when the loop is entered.  This
>    increases effectiveness of code motion optimizations, and reduces the need
>    for loop preconditioning.

I.e., if the later passes find some loop-invariant code, they will have a place to move that code to without a need to add a check, whether the loop will iterate at all.

> For all loops, copy the condition at the end of the loop body in front
>    of the loop.  This is beneficial since it increases efficiency of
>    code motion optimizations.  It also saves one jump on entry to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing `d` and removing the `goto` makes it stop being strange.

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;

unsigned my_atoi(const uchar *p) {//sentinel at end
  unsigned acm=0u;
  unsigned d=0; // initialized
//  goto LEnter;
  do{
    acm =  acm*10u + d;
//  LEnter:
    d = *p++ - '0';
  }while (d<10u);
  return acm;
}


 xor    eax,eax // acm=0
 xor    ecx,ecx // d=0
 data16 data16 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0] // nops, aligns to 16 bytes
 lea    eax,[rax+rax*4] // *5
 lea    eax,[rcx+rax*2] // *2+d
 movzx  ecx,BYTE PTR [rdi] // d=*p
 inc    rdi // p++
 add    ecx,0xffffffd0 // d-'0'
 cmp    ecx,0xa // d<10
 jb     4004e0 <my_atoi(unsigned char const*)+0x10>
 ret    
 data16 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
main:
 xor    eax,eax
 ret    
 nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
 nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
```

So the reason the compiler double the check is that you would jump into a none-aligned code. The central loop looks small enough to be in the loop-buffer of the CPU, but jumping into the middle of it might pollute the loop-buffer.

Comment: Actually what you're seeing is explained by Mikhail's answer: by writing the loop to do a useless `0 * 10` on the first iteration, you're satisfying gcc's condition that the whole loop body should run at least once if entered at all.  (The extra 2 cycles on the dep chain from the LEAs to multiply 0 by 10 might or might not be worth it to avoid the extra code-size.)

Comment: I don't think there's any need to worry about the loop buffer specifically, either for Core2 (where it's pre-decode blocks of code) or Nehalem + SnB (where it's post-decode, recycling uops in the queue that feeds the issue stage (the IDQ)).  If anything, you might temporarily end up with part of the loop body in two "ways" (lines) of the uop cache at once, though; once from jumping into the middle, and once from jumping to the top from the loop branch.  But if that exceeds the 3 lines per 32B block limit, it will settle down to a good pattern, and the jump into the loop can jump into a line.

Comment: Also note that the microcode update for Skylake (to fix the partial-register renaming crashes) disables the loop buffer entirely, so it always just runs from the uop cache (or decoders).  Which is fine, because SKL / SKX has excellent uop-cache throughput.